# How can I test a constant boolean expression?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a simple boolean expression involving only constants, like

```
4 + 5 = 9
```

Maybe (for debugging purposes - maybe the expression is a complicated LIKE expression) I want to just check to see if this expression is true or false. Is there a simple trick for doing this?

Currently I'm just using

```
SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table WHERE 4 + 5 = 9;
```

and seeing if I get anything back. I thought `SELECT 1 WHERE expression` might work, but no luck (MySQL 5.6.10). To be more precise about what I mean by "simple trick", let's say we want a command which **will run without modification on any server**. My current command doesn't fit the bill since we need to know the name of a schema and table in the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT (4 + 5 = 9) AS expression_result ;
```

It will either give you `1` (TRUE), `0` (FALSE) or `NULL` (UNKNOWN).

If you prefer string output instead of numbers:

```
SELECT CASE (4 + 5 = 9)
         WHEN TRUE  THEN 'TRUE'
         WHEN FALSE THEN 'FALSE'
         ELSE            'UNKNOWN'
       END AS expression_result ;
```

---

Alternatively:

```
SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE (4 + 5 = 9) ;
```

It will give you either `1` (TRUE) or no rows in the results (FALSE or UNKNOWN).

I'd prefer to use the first method as it distinguishes between all **three** possible results of a boolean expression in SQL (`TRUE / FALSE / UNKNOWN`).

Comment: So to be clear, `expression` is just a variable name that can be anything, like `result` or `value`.

Comment: Yes, it's just an alias/name for the column in the result set. You can pick any other name you like.

Comment: @JackM To obtain verbal result instead of number one you may use `SELECT ELT(COALESCE(1+(4 + 5 = 9),3),'FALSE','TRUE','UNKNOWN');`.

Comment: @Akina right, thnx! I added an alternative for that (prefering CASE to the cryptic ELT ;)